# How to remove duplicates in SAS data

Tags: sas, duplicates

I am trying to delete the observations in my data set that are the same across multiple variables.

For example

```
PIN       Start Date          End Date
1          Jan 1 2014         Jan 3 2014>
1         Jan 1 2014           Jan 3 2015
3         March 2 2014       March 5 2014
4        July 1 2014        July 8 2014
5         July 1 2014        July 8 2014
6        August 9 2014         August 24 2014
```

I would want to remove those with the same PIN and Start Date.

Answer (score 1):

Translate the string dates into SAS dates first.

```
data have2;
    set have(rename=(start_date = _start_date 
                     end_date   = _end_date) );

    start_date = input(strip(_start_date), anydtdte10.);
    end_date   = input(strip(_end_date), anydtdte10.);
   
    format start_date end_date date9.;

    drop _start_date _end_date;
run;
```

Then use `proc sort nodupkey`.

```
proc sort data=have2 nodupkey;
    by pin start_date;
run;
```

Comment: when I do that it shows no dups but when I just sort it by pin it shows 2 dups

Comment: Are your start dates and end dates SAS dates or strings?

Comment: The data is actual a string variable

Comment: You may have leading or trailing blanks. You should convert these into SAS dates first, then remove the duplicates. I'll edit my answer for this.

Comment: if they are not dates and just a text variable for instance address what would I have to do for that?

Comment: You should remove leading and trailing blanks of all your string variables with `strip()`

Comment: Ok I tried to do that for PIN and the address variable label and it didnt work. the date code did work.

Comment: There could be a number of things happening, such as invisible characters, extraneous text, etc. To figure it out, you'll need to post sample data that also includes address exactly as it is shown in your data (maybe even a .csv file).