# How to remove duplicates based on multiple columns in SAS?

Tags: sas, duplicates, proc-sql

I have table in SAS like below:

date types:

- COL1 - datetime
- COL2 - numeric
- date type of rest columns does not matter

  | COL1 | COL2 | ... | COLn |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 111 | ... | ... |
  | 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 111 | ... | ... |
  | 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 111 | ... | ... |
  | 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 222 | ... | ... |
  | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have many columns in my table and I need to delete duplicates in COL2 based on values in COL1, so as a result I need something like below:

| COL1 | COL2 | ... | COLn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 111 | ... | ... |
| 22AUG2022:15:46:38.000000 | 222 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can I do that using SAS Procedures or PROC SQL in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Comment: You said "delete duplicates in COL2 based on values in COL1", what does "based on" means?

Comment: it means that if values in COL1 and COL2 occur repeatedly the same then leave only 1 record with such values like in example :)

Comment: try `nodupkey` option in `proc sort`, there is an example(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706049/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-sas-data) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is which observation would you like to retrieve for a given by group? Perhaps the rest of the columns does not matter because they have the same values across rows?

If yes, use the `noduprecs` option in `proc sort`. It will delete  duplicated observations while `nodupkey` will delete those observations that have duplicate BY value.

Taking the below dataset as an example

```
       col1        col2  col3
 22AUG22:15:46:38   111   ABC
 22AUG22:15:46:38   111   DEF
 22AUG22:15:46:38   111   GHI
 22AUG22:15:46:38   222   JKL
```

---

Using `proc sort`

```
* delete observations that have duplicated BY values;
proc sort data=have out=want nodupkey equals;
by col1 col2;
run;

22AUG22:15:46:38 111 ABC  --> Keep the first record within the by group
22AUG22:15:46:38 222 JKL
```

Note that by using the `equals` option, observations with identical BY variable values are to retain the same relative positions in
the output data set as in the input data set. See more on
[Does NODUPKEY Select the First Record in a By Group?](https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/PO/PharmaSUG-2012-PO02.pdf)

```
* delete observations that have duplicated values;
proc sort data=have out=want noduprecs equals;
by col1 col2;
run;

22AUG22:15:46:38 111 ABC
22AUG22:15:46:38 111 DEF
22AUG22:15:46:38 111 GHI
22AUG22:15:46:38 222 JKL
```

Using the `noduprecs` option will not remove any observation with our example dataset as `col3` has different values. You are not showing the rest of the columns in your example but shall they share the same values across rows, you might want to use it.

---

You could alternatively do it using `proc summary`

```
proc summary data=have nway;
class col1 col2;
id col3;
output out=want(drop=_type_ _freq_);
run;

22AUG22:15:46:38 111 GHI --> Keep the last value within the by group
22AUG22:15:46:38 222 JKL
```

Note that `proc summary` with a `class` statement provides a more efficient alternative than `proc sort` by avoiding the need for sorting in advance.

---

Or even using `proc sql`

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select col1, col2, col3
from have
group by col1, col2
having col3 = max(col3);
quit;

22AUG22:15:46:38 111 GHI --> max value within the group by columns
22AUG22:15:46:38 222 JKL
```

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select col1, col2, col3
from have
group by col1, col2
having col3 = min(col3);
quit;

22AUG22:15:46:38 111 ABC --> min value within the group by columns
22AUG22:15:46:38 222 JKL
```